# Adjust Resize for edittext

Tags: android, xml, material-design, manifest

Hello i have added everything in my android manifest but the layout is cutting my xml when the keyboard is shown. what i expect is that nothing is cut off.

here is my xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Chat.MessageListFragmentLadoComercial">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle_image_chat_cliente"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombre_cliente_chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Nombre Cliente"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_hasta_abajo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="9">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="22dp" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <!-- A horizontal line between the chatbox and RecyclerView -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"

            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Enter message"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:maxLines="6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_chatbox_send"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my manifest portion...

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Chat.MessageListActivityLadoComercial"
            android:label="Chat"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


        </activity>
```

Here is how it looks like....

[image: As you can see the horizontal linear layout gets cut off]

[image]

So i want to do is that the horizontal linear layout is not cut off ive tried everything but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: try using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity tag of android manifest

Comment: nope adjustPan doesnt do the trick either!

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, in your case `linearLayout2` because it can span over all the available space hence can get resized when the keyboard pops up. But LinearLayout don't get resized in the resizing process so your top linearlayout with circleimageview and title can't get resized.